# Update Shiny App Data without republishing App?

Tags: shiny, rstudio, shiny-server

I am currently creating a Shiny App for an employer using the Leaflet and Shiny packages within RStudio. I am making a map displaying projections for an upcoming election. These projections change quite frequently and the map will have to change to accommodate these fluctuations. We will be hosting the map on a private server (not shinyapps.io).

Currently, I am loading the projection data into RStudio as a CSV, then merging it with the Shapefile of the electoral districts:

```
  projection_data <- read.csv("./Data/projection_data.csv")
  elect_districts <- shapefile("./Data/ed_simple.shp")
  ed_projection <- merge(elect_districts, projection_data, by='ED_ID')
```

Is it possible to update the CSV file and have those changes represented in the published app, WITHOUT republishing the app?

I am hoping to make the update process as simple as possible, as it will be up to my employer to update the map after I have finished this assignment.

[The projection data is very simple. We have the name of the district and the projected winner. The projected winner (party_prob) is the variable that will need to be updated.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uv5rA.png)

Comment: You should connect a database to the app, which will make periodic requests to update its required data.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Simply write these two lines in your R console. It will be updated.

```
library(rsconnect)
rsconnect::deployApp( local_path_of_your_app )
```

Comment: Doesn't this count as republishing the app, which OP does not want to do?